# Query error while working with PL/pgSQL arrays

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have this function:

```
create or replace function insert_aereo( aereo_type[] ) returns text as $$
begin
   return 'ok';
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

and this is the parameter type that I created:

```
create type aereo_type as (codice int, modello varchar, marca varchar);
```

Then I call my function:

```
select insert_aereo('{123, "ciao", "pippo"}');
```

but I get this error:

```
ERROR:  function insert_aereo(unknown) is not unique at character 8
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
STATEMENT:  select insert_aereo('{123, "ciao", "pippo"}');
ERROR:  function insert_aereo(unknown) is not unique
LINE 1: select insert_aereo('{123, "ciao", "pippo"}');
               ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How can I fix it? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a bad format for composed types:

The correct format is:

'{"(123, ciao, pippo)", "(...)"}

see: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/rowtypes.html

or ARRAY[(1,'ciao','pippo')]::t[]

Pavel